# Using angular2, typescript and restangular2, no provider for http error

Tags: rest, http, angular

i am using this for rest requests (or trying) : https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ng2-restangular/

I am using this yeoman generator:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2-typescript

the out of the box generated project looks fine,

i then follow the instructions in ng2-resangular but when running this i get the following error:

```
core.umd.js?e2a5:2840 Error: No provider for Http!
    at NoProviderError.Error (native)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:1104:38)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:1235:20)
    at new NoProviderError (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:1266:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:2736:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:2764:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:2727:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:2536:25)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:160:113)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:165:135)
    at NgModuleInjector.AppModuleInjector.getInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:306:51)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6717:31)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.injectorGet (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9150:49)
    at DebugAppView.injectorGet (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9389:53)
    at DebugAppView.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:15:63)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.createHostView (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9122:25)
    at DebugAppView.createHostView (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9379:56)
    at ComponentFactory.create (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:5478:29)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6547:44)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6456:93)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6456:46)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6424:31)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:232:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:5972:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:231:32)
    at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:114:43)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:502:57)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:265:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:5963:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:264:40)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:154:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2178:2), <anonymous>:401:35)
```

app.modules.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HttpModule, Headers, Response, ResponseOptions} from "@angular/http";
import { RestangularModule } from 'ng2-restangular';
import {routing, appRoutingProviders} from './app.routing';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AboutComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing,
        // Importing RestangularModule and making default configs for restanglar
        RestangularModule.forRoot((RestangularProvider: any) => {
                RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://api.test.local/v1');
                RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer UDXPx-Xko0w4BRKajozCVy20X11MRZs1'});
            }
        ),
    ],
    providers: [appRoutingProviders, HttpModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

app.components.js

```
mport {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../css/main.css';
import {Restangular} from "ng2-restangular";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private restangular: Restangular) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // GET http://api.test.local/v1/users/2/accounts
        this.restangular.one('users', 2).all("accounts").getList();
    }
}
```

i must admit i was a little lost with this error so i tried to add the following in app.modules:

```
import {HttpModule, Headers, Response, ResponseOptions} from "@angular/http";
```

but that did not seem to do anything

finally i added this into vendor.ts

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/forms';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

import 'rxjs';

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'ng2-restangular/dist/umd/ng2-restangular'
```

the last line was not a requirement to add from reading the ng2-restangular git repo but it looked like i needed to, not sure if this correct though.

any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok so in app.components.js the offending code is the constructor, if i remove the code from app.component it works fine, leading me to believe the RestAngular library is loaded into my app but for some reason attempting to use it results in the error shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in ng2-restangular! It was updated to version 0.1.9 and should work now. More information on the [repository](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ng2-restangular/issues/5).

I needed to remove the whole "node_modules" folder and reinstall using:

```
npm install
```

And now every thing works.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpModules shouldn't in the providers array, neither should the appRoutingProviders be in there

`providers: [appRoutingProviders, HttpModule]`

`providers: []`

Comment: the appRoutingProviders were in there as part of the original generator.

Comment: Did removing both fix your issue?

Comment: no removing it had no affect on the error, the error remains the same.